# Cannot delete a file which seemingly has some filesystem corruption attached to it

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I was editting audio files in Sony Sound Forge pro 11.0, but when I went to open one today, it caused sound forge to crash.
Subsequently, I discovered that renaming it would cause Explorer to crash, trying to delete it will cause it to get stuck on the preparing to delete screen, asking it to display properties does nothing, and writing a program to delete it causes said program to hang.

I wrote a batch file which in past has helped me delete undeletable files which looks like this:
"rd /s "SFX.WAV"
pause"
This however reports that E:\The Game\sounds\interacts is not a valid directory.
Everything else in the directory works fine, though. Funnily enough, due to the one corrupt file inside its structure, you cannot delete or rename any parent folders.

Any help deleting this little trouble maker is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FileAssassin? It might be helpful https://www.malwarebytes.com/fileassassin/

Comment: Tried it, and while its a great program to add to my arsenal, it also hangs just like all other programs that try to touch this file.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use Unlocker for this issue.

[Unlocker](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/Unlocker.html)

Comment: Thanks! I avoided unlocker because I had tried it with prior corruption issues with no success, but it absolutely worked perfectly this time!

Comment: I'm glad worked out this time.   Its a great tool for these special situations.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.